# Proving a set equality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Hi I am learning group theory and encountered this:
$$(B\cap (A\cap B)')\cup (B'\cap (A\cap B)) = B\cap (A'\cup B').$$

I don't understand how this is true, could someone please show me proof?

Thanks

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ subgroups? What does $A'$ mean here? Derived subgroup?

Comment: What are $A$, $B$, etc.? Where is the union and intersection taking place?

Comment: A better word for "equals statement" is "equality".

Comment: Have you tried a truth table? It would be huge but I think it would be a good exercise in learning equivalence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming the prime denotes complementation: The second term on the left, $B'\cap(A\cap B)$, is empty, since $B$ and $B'$ are disjoint. That leaves $B\cap(A\cap B)'$. You can use De Morgan's law $(A\cap B)'=A'\cup B'$ to transform  this into the right-hand side.

Comment: @Jason, if this answers your question, please clarify it and retag it as (elementary-set-theory).

Comment: @Lhf: I have done it anyway. Jason, can put it back if needed.

Comment: @joriki: Aw so me thanks I was missing the disjoint definition :)  btw how do you print the math formulas so nicely?

Comment: @Jason: Seems you've figured that one out in the meantime? :-)

Comment: I guys I have he he :)

Comment: @Jason: We use MathJax (a form of $\LaTeX$) to typeset our equations. A big manual is [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/). I learn by imitation, so I often look at how other people have formatted their answers by clicking the edit button next to their posts to see the 'raw code' behind the formatting.

Comment: @Michael: I used to look at the raw code by clicking the edit button, too, but then someone pointed out that you can actually right-click on any $\TeX$ output and select "Show Source" to see the code. (This shows everything except for the enclosing (single or double) dollar signs.)

Comment: Oh. That's quite nifty. Thanks for the tip! I will say though that, though I'm fairly decent at typesetting my problems sets, I never knew about `$$` and `\begin{align}` until I looked at some of the longer answers.